# extracting a set amount of lines from a Text file - Python

Tags: python, text

let us imagine I have a text file with the following inside of it: (each line starts with a number and contains information next to it which I need)

> 1   325315
>
> 2   234265
>
> 3   345345
>
> 4   234234
>
> 5   373432
>
> 6   436721
>
> 7   325262
>
> 8   235268

How would I go about extracting the lines that are after number 3 and before number 6 for example? While keeping the other data that is held on the same line.

I have a very large text file ~1000 lines, which I need to extract the lines starting with 300 through to 800. Either extract or remove the lines that I do not need, either way is ok.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you share the code till you have tried?

Comment: Is the first number of each line is a sequence?

Comment: I would say ~1000 lines is quite a small text file

Comment: Very sorry Jeril - I am relatively new to Python and had a few attempts but they were extremely dodgy and far off the mark so I thought it would be best to not include them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
def extract(file, fr, to):
    f = open(file, "r+")

    [next(f) for i in range(fr)]

    return [f.readline() for i in range(to - fr)]
```

or extract only the 2nd column

```
    return [f.readline().split()[1] for i in range(500)]
```

Output:

```
extract("file",3,5)

['4 234234\n', '5 373432\n']
```

Comment: How this will extract data between third line and sixth line?

Answer (score 0):

Do like this.

```
l = [line for line in (open('xyz.txt','r')).readlines() if int(line.split()[0]) > 3 and int(line.split()[0]) < 6 ]
```

Output:(Output will be lines between 3 and 6)

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
['4 234234\n', '5 373432\n']

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indexes are not sequential

```
outList=[]
with open('somefile') as f:
    for line in f:
        a=line.split()
        if 3<int(a[0])<6:
            outlist.append(a[1]) # or append(line), append(a) depending on needs
```

Or just use `numpy.loadtxt` and use array methods.

Comment: Can we have  if 3<=int(line.split()[0])<=6: instead of if 3<=int(a[0])<=6: ?

Comment: Also <= should be only <. Same for => since OP wants lines between 3 and 6 not inclusive.

Comment: fixed the `<=`, but depending on the output required retaining the `.split()` could be preferred.